# Brunch doesn't compile uikit js files

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, brunch, getuikit

I am trying to compile my code using brunch, but the line `js/components.js` doesn't compile.

I tried changing the path from regex to a normal link, but nothing seems to make my components.js to be written.

Running brunch build -d doesn't give me any info about any of those files.

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^7.0.1",
    "brunch": "^2.10.17",
    "clean-css-brunch": "^2.10.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "^2.10.0",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.10.8",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^2.10.0"
  }
```

```
// brunch-config.js
module.exports = {
    paths: {
        'public': 'web',
        'watched': ['app/Resources']
    },
    files: {
        javascripts: {
            joinTo: {
                'js/app.js': /^app/,
                // the next line is where my problem is
                'js/components.js': /^bower_components\/uikit\/dist\/js\/components/
            }
        },
        stylesheets: {
            joinTo: {
                'css/style.css': /style.scss/
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I expect the file components.js to be written in my web/js/ directory, but nothing ever happens.